# How to determine whether code is getting executed in a console app or in a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

How to determine whether code is getting executed in a console app or in a windows service?

Comment: You could check what user it is executing as. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @silky: The user for a service can be any any named user account, so it wouldn't be enough information to distinguish between a "running as a windows service" or "running as a client app".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst it's not console specific (i.e. this will return true when running as a winforms app as well) I've used the following

```
if (Environment.UserInteractive)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hi I'm being ran as a console app");
}
```